# Undo Redo in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have added a graphics view in my Qt applocation in which different items can be added like line, ellipse How can undo redo actions can be applied in graphics view. Following is the code for adding items such as line.
mainwindow.cpp

```
connect(ui->lineButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(drawLine()));
```

line.cpp

```
void line::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* e){
    if(e->button()==Qt::LeftButton) {
        if(mFirstClick){
            x1 = e->pos().x();
            y1 = e->pos().y();
            mFirstClick = false;
            mSecondClick = true;
        }

        else if(!mFirstClick && mSecondClick){
            x2 = e->pos().x();
            y2 = e->pos().y();
            mPaintFlag = true;
            mSecondClick = false;
            update();
        }
    }
    QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(e);
    update();
}

void line:: paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget){
    QRectF rect = boundingRect();
    if(mPaintFlag){
        QPen paintpen(Qt::red);
        paintpen.setWidth(4);

        QPen linepen(Qt::black);
        linepen.setWidth(1);

        QPoint p1;
        p1.setX(x1);
        p1.setY(y1);

        painter->setPen(paintpen);
        painter->drawPoint(p1);

        QPoint p2;
        p2.setX(x2);
        p2.setY(y2);

        painter->setPen(paintpen);
        painter->drawPoint(p2);

        painter->setPen(linepen);
        painter->drawLine(p1, p2);
    }
}

void line::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e)
{
    if (e->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier) {
        stuff << e->pos();
        update();
        return;
    }
    QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(e);
}

void line::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e)
{
    QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent(e);
    update();
}
```

drawLine slot

```
 void MainWindow::drawLine(){
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    line *item = new line;
    scene->addItem(item);
    qDebug() << "Line Created";

}
```

Edited:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionUndo_triggered()
    {
        undoView = new QUndoView(undoStack);
       ui->actionUndo= undoStack->createUndoAction(this, tr("&Undo"));
     ui->actionUndo->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Undo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might go ahead and implement the command pattern in your application. This is a pattern found in the book made by The Gang of Four **Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software**. I think a better explanation than what I have in mind for the pattern can be found here: [Command Pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/command.html#undo-and-redo).

While the article is focused in games, you might as well apply it to your code. Good Luck!

Comment: No need to re-invent the wheel. Qt comes with an [Undo framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qundo.html)

Comment: Well, that is one function I will now use in future projects. Thank you!

Comment: I have edited my code. I am using QUndoStack but no error and no output.